# Reproducibility in TeXShop and Overleaf

Tags: pdftex

I am trying to compile the following piece of code on TeXShop using Tex Live 2023

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\section*{Figures and Tables}\label{figures}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\multicolumn{1}{p{1\textwidth}}{ \footnotesize \emph{Notes:} hello hello this is a footnote meant to be under a figure. } 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

but get the following error:

```
/filename.tex: 85: Misplaced \omit. 
\multispan -> \omit
```

which points to the following line:
`\multicolumn{1}{p{1\textwidth}}{ \footnotesize \emph{Notes:} hello hello this is a footnote meant to be under a figure. }` . However, I do know this is not a syntax error, as the code compiles successfully using Overleaf, suggesting that there may be an issue with either my installed packages or my LaTeX distribution (Tex Live 2023), or the settings of TeXShop.

Here is what I have tried, without success:

- Updating TeX Live with `tlmgr update --all`
- Update all packages in the TeX Live Utility app.
- Update the filename database with `sudo texhash`
- Update the paths in the TeXShop settings. Specifically, I tried replacing the default paths (`pdftex --file-line-error --synctex=1`) for `pdfTeX`, that is `Tex` and `Latex` with the location of my Tex Live `/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/universal-darwin/pdftex`.

Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT:

here is my log-file:

```
Th./testing.tex:7: Undefined control sequence.
\@ampacol ->\@addamp \@acol 
                            
l.7 ...is a footnote meant to be under a figure. }
                                                  
? is is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./testing.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-08-29>
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./testing.aux)
./testing.tex:7: Misplaced \omit.
\multispan ->\omit 
                   \@multispan 
l.7 ...is a footnote meant to be under a figure. }
                                                  
?
```

Comment: You can't use `\multicolumn` outside a `tabular` environment or similar. If that code compiles on OverLeaf, that would be bizarre and a problem. Not the source of the error, but your preamble will prove a constant source of niggles, if not actual errors, if you don't prune it from time to time. Only load packages you need. Also, you're loading some in the wrong order. Load `hyperref` last unless you know otherwise. And avoid loading things twice.

Comment: The more packages you load but don't understand, the more your code is prone to errors. Try deleting packages little by little to see whether the problem disappears (or at least lessens). Even if it doesn't work, it's easier for us to help to answer you when you remove the packages unrelated to your problem.

Comment: @cfr and @gz839918 thank you for your responses. I have updated the post to remove all the libraries I posted earlier (I had believed the issue I am encountering could have been somehow related to the packages I was using), but still see the same error. In addition, a new error appears for the same line: ```Undefined control sequence``` (I have also attached the new log-file). I have also noticed that this same code on overleaf still compiles, but the line using ```\multicolumn``` is bolded in red and indicates the exact same error messages,   
yet again still compiling.

Comment: In other words, it seems Overleaf is ignoring these errors and are somehow non-fatal. Would there be a way to setup TeXShop such that it behaves in the same way ?

Comment: overleaf doesn't ignore the errors, you will have  red error count above the pdf view. any such pdf is just a debugging aid not a usable document. you can get a local tex to scroll past errors by typing `s` to the error message or using `\scrollmode` for example

Comment: You can certainly do it in terminal, even if you can't do it in TeXShop. But you can't just ignore errors except as a very temporary measure. No PDF which results is reliable.

Comment: This reports 3 errors for me in Overleaf.

Comment: May I suggest a more constructive approach? Could you tell us what you are trying to do with that `\multicolumn`? Are you trying to make a table? I'm guessing not, but .... If not, what are you trying to do? Are you trying to put a note under a figure? Perhaps you want `\caption{A caption for the figure}`?

Comment: Wild guess: do you just want `{\footnotesize \emph{Notes:} hello hello this is a footnote meant to be under a figure. }` on that line? It will take (up to) `\textwidth` anyway. You're not dealing with columns as you might in a table.  A `figure` takes the width of the text block.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the cause is an easy to spot syntax error, puzzling figures with tables.